# What is the thing that dies after drinking water?

Tags: riddle

Answer the following puzzle.

> What is the thing that dies after drinking water?

**Note:**

> That thing every day died minimum 4 to 5 time.

**P.S:** Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Straight away, first things I thought of: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Guvefg & Sver$]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible answer:

> Thirst

Also can be:

> Drought

Answer (score 4):

*What is the thing that dies after drinking water?*

Sadly, it is my

> iPhone

*Note: That thing every day died minimum 4 to 5 time.*

> I really need to stop dropping it in the toilet.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> FIRE

Explanation

> Fire dies upon getting contact with water

Comment: Well try, but not expected answer.